# cygstdc++-6.dll Entry Point Not Found

Tags: c++, gcc, cygwin

I have the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string myString = "This is a string";
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it with g++ I get the following error:

> The procedure entry point
>   _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1EPKcRKS3_ could not be located in the dynamic link library cygstdc++-6.dll.

I've tried re-installing cygwin but that didn't fix anything, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Looks like a broken compiler.

Comment: My guess is you have some old cygwin dlls in your path.